# I need help finding the limits of integration for this parametric equation.

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, parametric

The equation is $$x= 2\cot(\theta), y=2\sin^2(\theta)$$ $$0\le \theta\le\pi  $$
I believe the answer is $4\pi$ but I keep getting $-4\pi$ I know this is wrong because the area is negative and I believe I need to reverse my limits to get the correct answer yet I don't know why. $-4\theta\bigg|_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi}$ Is my final answer

Comment: I assume here $t$ should be $\theta$?

Comment: Yes sorry about that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: More context might be useful

Comment: Do I need to rearrange the limits for this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to find the area under the curve, length or something else? Please clarify.

Comment: Area under the curve

Comment: It is helpful to sketch the parametric curve. What shape roughly does it have? Which direction is curve going? What integral did you use to find the area?

Comment: This is a "witch" (_avverisera_) of Agnesi:  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WitchofAgnesi.html .   Your parameter is "tracing out" the curve from right-to-left, which is likely why you are getting a negative area.

Comment: Surely you know that cot(0)= 1/tan(0) is infinity.  that is why you need to integrate from pi to 0.